# Problem autosizing second view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, resize, autosize

Once a view is called from appdelegate, it is properly loaded but not autosized correctly, on the bottom you see last lines from previous view! On xib file, view mode property is set to scale to fill but I tried others and still happening the same... Thanks for any idea to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check Interface Builder, is the view using any of the **Simulated User Interface Elements**?  That isn't directly answering your question but it might be worth a look, e.g. the status bar is normally simulated by default.

Comment: Thanx for answering! Yes, status bar is simulated and that is exactly same pixel lines missing at the bottom, so, view is overlap with status bar, not at his bottom! I tried to resize it with rect but doesn't work...

Comment: I'm not sure if it's going to fill if the content in the child view isn't larger then the parent, but you've manually tried to re-size it in the View Size inspector?

Comment: I already tried to resize it using view size inspector but width, height are locked, and x y can only be set graphical position and height is always set to 460!
If I try to resize it like self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 350, 500), it works but first time that view is called original non desired size appears and turns to new one like an animation, it doesn't appear instantly!! Thanks again for your comment

Answer (score 0):

The standart way to control autosizing is by
`self.View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`(or st. else)
`self.View.autoresizesSubviews = YES;`

You might also try to just set the size manually